# Cordova Android emulator black screen when running Cordova's hello world app

Tags: android, cordova, windows-7, android-emulator

I'm trying to get started with Android development using Cordova by trying to build and run Cordova's "hello world" program following their [`Creating your first app` guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html). Nothing fancy - just trying to build and run the super-ultra-simple hello world program that gets created with the command `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`.

I've successfully followed the instructions up through "Building the App" for Android. When I get to the step for "Test the App", it fires up the emulator, but all I get is a black screen in the android device frame and some error messages in the terminal for it. See screenshot of black screen w/ terminal output below:

[image: Screenshot of black screen w/ terminal output]

From googling around on my own, I've come across the `Failed to create D3D shaders` error from the terminal output before with other OpenGL-based applications which have worked for me on other platforms. As far as I can tell, it seems to have something to do with ANGLE on Windows 7's version of Direct X, but I haven't been able to find any clear instructions on how to fix it.

The platform I'm using is Windows 7. The AVD I've got configured for the emulator is Nexus 5X using Android 7.0 x86 Nougat, using the default configurations provided by Android Studio v2.3.3. The version of Cordova I'm using is v7.0.1.

I have also confirmed that I am able to run the "hello world" app directly on a real Android device using `cordova run android`. It works successfully on there. So just running it in the emulator is the problem.

Help?